# Mysql Order by Tweak

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a database with nearly 100 fields. 
DB structure is

> id | comment | time

I need to fetch only 5 **newest** record (I can get those records using ORDER by time DESC). But while printing them I need to print the oldest of those 5 records first and proceed in reverse in a way that the newest record will be printed last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after fetching result set in ascending order with a limit of number of rows

you can do this to print them in reverse order (descending order)

```
$data= array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$records = array_reverse($data);
```

OR

This could be done with [mysql_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Directly taken from [here](http://www.topwebhosts.org/wp/lamp/mysql/how-to-reverse-a-mysql-result-set/)

```
for ($i = mysql_num_rows($resultset) – 1; $i >= 0; $i–) {
    mysql_data_seek($resultset, $i);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['abc'] . ' ' . $row['xyz'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.* FROM (
    SELECT id, comment, time FROM table1
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 5 ) as s
ORDER BY s.time ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's `array_reverse()` function on your result list.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use also something like this:

```
select * from (select * from table_name where 1=1 order by time desc 
limit 5) as tbl order by tbl.time;
```

Edit if you have a lot of accesses to this statement it would be much better to represent it as materialized view. Though there are no materialized views in mysql it is possible to simulate them (http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/207808)

Using a materialized view or a simulated materialized view will seriously outperform the suggested php approaches. Most of the mentioned ones consume to much memory anyways .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something along the lines of (untested):

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, comment, time
    FROM
        table
    ORDER BY
        time DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY
    time ASC
```

---

**UPDATE**
Apparently, the "derived table must have its own alias" ([error #1248](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1248?sort=newest)). Other answers have already done this, so I'll jump on the bandwagon. Below you'll find the revised (and tested) query:

```sql
SELECT
    derived.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, comment, time
    FROM
        table
    ORDER BY
        time DESC
    LIMIT 5
) AS derived
ORDER BY
    derived.time ASC
```

By the way, this is [supported as of MySQL 4.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/ansi-diff-subqueries.html).